# How do I move an SQL Server database from one local PC to another?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm using SQL Server 2014 express on a local PC to store a large dataset (3 GB+) for a university research project, and it has worked out really good so far.

However now there is a need for me to move it to another new PC, so my question is:

How do I backup the database in a way so that I can access and use it again on the new PC?

Comment: I already read that, but I'm no SQL Server expert, so I simply would like some confirmation from the experts, so that i won't end up with a database backup that I for some reason cannot get access to.

Comment: @SuppaiKamo Make copies of everything and try it.

Comment: Ok, so basically by copying the entire instance folder, I cannot end up in a situation where I cannot get access to my data?

Comment: That's not what @johnny said at all. The #1 rule for any backup operation is to test that the restore actually works. A backup that does not restore is not a backup.

Comment: You're right, I guess I should just test it out when I get the new PC.

Comment: Yes, or test it on another old box if you have one laying around. A VM is also quite a handy tool, if your restore attempt only partially works then just roll the VM back and try again until you get it right. Seriously, too many people feel safe in the knowledge that they have a backup, but have never tried to restore it - and that's when it bites them. You owe it to yourself to test your strategy if your data is valuable to you. One final tip, write every step down as you do it, don't rely on your memory, no matter how good you think it is... Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, the data is valuable to me, which is why I'm attempting to preempt ä potential problem, so tip is valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From SQL Server Management Studio right click on the database and select backup from somewhere from the menu. After that transfer the backup file to the other PC. Then on the other PC right click on the server from SQL Server Management studio then click restore database and select the backup file.

Here is a link with a good tutorial: http://www.serverintellect.com/support/sqlserver/database-backup-ssmse/

By the way you should archive the backup file. With 7zip you can get a nice ratio on an database backup file.

Comment: I am accessing the database using a user I created, SQL server authentication, so do I in some way need to account for that when making the backup? Or is the backup simply open for all (the database is not encrypted), which is fine as its only me using it. My fear is that I cannot get access to the database after restoring.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to restore a sql database on another instance.

1. Make a backup to your disk drive.
2. Copy the .BAK file to the target computer.
3. Create a new database with the same name...(empty)
4. Select the new database on the target machine select the restore option.
5. Point the restore from hard disk option to the directory in which you saved the .BAK in step 2.

Comment: I am accessing the database using a user I created, SQL server authentication, so do I in some way need to account for that when making the backup? Or is the backup simply open for all (the database is not encrypted), which is fine as its only me using it. My fear is that I cannot get access to the database after restoring.

Comment: You will have to script or re-create your users as the credentials do not get restored at the server level.

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server Management Studio:

- Connect to your local istance
- Right-click your database
- Select Tasks > Backup

A wizard will guide you through the backup process.
On the other pc the procedure is the same.

- Connect to local istance
- Right-click your database
- Select Tasks > Restore

Comment: I am accessing the database using a user I created, SQL server authentication, so do I in some way need to account for that when making the backup? Or is the backup simply open for all (the database is not encrypted), which is fine as its only me using it. My fear is that I cannot get access to the database after restoring.

Comment: The backup is not linked to any kind of authentication. You need to have the right permission on the target server in order to be able to restore your db.

Comment: Ok, as it is a local system only used by me, I can set permissions in any way I feel, so that's promising. Still I'll test it out before comitting to any solution.

Answer (score 0):

These all good answers, but if you are like me and using a PC with limited access rights because your organization has things locked down, you won't be able to get to the folder where your .bak file is stored.  To get around this restriction, when doing the backup select a different Destination, like C:\MSSQL\Backup<yourdbname>.bak .  Be sure to also delete the initial destination the wizard identified, or you'll get an error doing the backup (don't worry, it will get recreated the next time you back up the database).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31929046)